# Can't tap on checkboxes in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I make tests on React Native. I use `react-native-paper` for this. This is my code:

```js
{(!props.question.isSingleAnswer && props.question.answers.length) && 
     <View>
          {props.question.answers.map((item) => (
             <List.Item
                 key={item.id.toString()}
                 title={item.title}
                 left={checkProps => <Checkbox {...checkProps} status='unchecked' onPress={() => addAnswer(props.question, item)}/>}
             />
          ))}
    </View>
}
```

But I can't check checkboxes. The same problem with radio buttons.

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

UPD: the problem was solved. Question is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have the `status` of your checkbox to always `unchecked`, whereas you should always set `status` of your checkbox to anything dynamic for eg use a state.

I don't know what your `addAnswer` function does so have a look at [this](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/checkbox.html#usage) example for reference.

Comment: My addAnswer function adds answer to the array of answers. When I click at checkbox, it becomes checked. Also my questions and answers are dynamic. So I don't know how to realize it.

Comment: Just add one more piece of state like `checked` and toggle it each time you add or remove any question or answers.